# Color Picker UI in admin is not correct

Tags: plugins, options, color-picker

I need to have color picker settings filed in my plugin. I have registered a field and its saving value in the database correctly. But, in the admin area the picker user interface is not correct I think.

It should look like this:
[image: it should look like this]

but in my case, it looks like
[image: but in my case it looks like]

Here is the code I have for registering the field

```
        add_settings_field( 'iconBg', 'Background Color', array( $this, 'bg_settings_field' ), 'wpfyscroller-settings-page', 'wpfyscrollersection' );
        register_setting( 'wpfyscrollerfields', 'iconBg', array('sanitize_callback'=>'sanitize_hex_color', 'default'=> '#000000') );

        //Callback function
        function bg_settings_field() { ?>
 
        
        <input type="text" name="iconBg" value="<?php echo get_option('iconBg') ?>" class="cpa-color-picker" >
         
    <?php }
```

Here is the code for enqueueing js

```
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_admin_js' ) );
    function enqueue_admin_js() { 
 
        // Make sure to add the wp-color-picker dependecy to js file
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cpa_custom_js', plugins_url( '/assets/js/colorPicker.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), '', true  );
    }
```

NOTE: My 'jquery' dependency already loaded with another script.

Here is the JS code:

```
(function ($) {$(function () {

// Add Color Picker to all inputs that have 'color-field' class
$(".cpa-color-picker").wpColorPicker();});})(jQuery);
```

Not sure what mistake I did, any help will be apricated.

Thanks

Comment: Even if another script has already loaded a dependency, if your code relies on that dependency, it should specify it in the dependency array. WordPress performs dependency resolution behind the scenes, and with the variability of hook order, the order in which scripts are loaded can be fairly unpredictable. All of that said, have you verified that your script is loading and executing? Do you receive any errors or warnings in the JS console?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @bosco
The script was loading fine and the console was clean. 
I have found the issue, I forgot to enqueue 'wp-color-picker' CSS script

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted :)